# Something in my regex is not recognizing images served from a location without an extension as valid urls

Tags: php, regex, image, url, preg-match

I have been working on a small script designed to pack an entire webpage into one single html file. I've been working on it all day, and so far, all images that have a proper extension are converted and inserted properly, however, some images that do not have a proper extension are skipped.

Here's my code

```
function getimages($string) {
    $html = $string;
    $html = str_replace("https://", "http://", $html);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
        if (preg_match("|^(https?:)\/\/|i", $src)) {
                $type = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
        $data = file_get_contents($src, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        if (strlen(bin2hex($data))/2 > 1) {
            if (strlen($type) < 3) {
                $type="png";
            }
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        $image->setAttribute("src", $base64);
        }
        }

        $image->removeAttribute("srcset");
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
return $html;
}
```

Here is an example image url that would be skipped over

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTJgMWr6TgV_3mJcF9Q9jRw6K_-oTLfRErLcKGTFXhn-pMQLJB24MhbTHt4A

This is so close to working exactly as I want it, but I am really new to regex, and IDK what I'm doing that's causing those urls to not be processed, please cast a line my way.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the regex.  Most likely the `file_get_contents` is failing or `strlen(bin2hex($data))/2 > 1` if blank page or maybe redirect.

Comment: okay, so I disabled the blank page check, and now it processes the urls, but returns no data, I am assuming because of a re-direct, or some other trickery that prevents the image from being directly downloaded. Lets assume for simplicity sake, that these images are not directly accessible to my script at the urls given. How would I make my script follow the whole chain of redirects s I can get the image being served by that url?

Comment: Not sure that you'll ever get the image but https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Comment: well poo. Changing to download with curl makes all of the images fail to download. I did make some sort of progress though, I am now able to fetch the image of the google maps result for the search (paris), after changing the user-agent to mimic an ipad, however, all the other images still fail to download. Would it be safe to assume that these images are behind some kind of scrape sheild?

Comment: Okay, so if I access the individual files, one at a time, directly, instead of as part of the page, I can successfully download the files. Any way I could leverage this behavior to maybe make some sort script/code that could download everything it can currently access, then to do a secondary sweep for any unconverted image tags, and somehow maybe execute the downloads in some sort of separate thread or process to trick the source into believing the images are being accessed directly and individually?

Comment: Just want to note here that I got it to work, I had to use a seperate cgi language which sends a singe direct request to the image file, then returns it as base64 encoded data. When the returned image size is empty, the php script will call this aucgi script through file_get_contents via localhost, and the secondary script will handle fetching the binary data, and return it as base64.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.

I had to use a seperate cgi script language in my cgi bin, here's an example of how I coded it, in aucgi(if you need it, google is your friend)

```
##WebApp
<?au3
#include <inet.au3>
echo(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(base64(_InetGetsource((StringReplace($_GET_raw, "url=", "")))), @CR, ""), @LF, ""), @CRLF, ""))
Func base64($vCode, $bEncode = True, $bUrl = False)

    Local $oDM = ObjCreate("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    If Not IsObj($oDM) Then Return SetError(1, 0, 1)

    Local $oEL = $oDM.createElement("Tmp")
    $oEL.DataType = "bin.base64"

    If $bEncode then
        $oEL.NodeTypedValue = Binary($vCode)
        If Not $bUrl Then Return $oEL.Text
        Return StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace($oEL.Text, "+", "-"),"/", "_"), @LF, "")
    Else
        If $bUrl Then $vCode = StringReplace(StringReplace($vCode, "-", "+"), "_", "/")
        $oEL.Text = $vCode
        Return $oEL.NodeTypedValue
    EndIf

EndFunc ;==>base64
?>
```

Then in my php script I simply add a conditional statement that says if the returned data is null or empty, to instead make a request through this aucgi script with file_get_contents

```
if (strlen(bin2hex($data))/2 > 1) {
            if (strlen($type) < 3) {
                $type="png";
            }
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        $image->setAttribute("src", $base64);
        } else {
            $base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' .file_get_contents("http://localhost/cgi-bin/passthrough.au3?url=".$src);
        $image->setAttribute("src", $base64);
        }
```